# Mongocxx-driver doesn't build during installation

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm following the tutorial at http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/ .
I have successfully compiled/installed c driver as described at http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html. However, when building the cxx driver using

```
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost\boost_1_59_0 ..
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I receive the following errors:

```
"D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\src\mongocxx\mongocxx.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\src\mongocxx\gridfs\downloader.cpp(80): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous [D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\src\mongocxx\mongocxx.vcxproj]


"D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\src\mongocxx\mongocxx_mocked.vcxproj" (default target) (6) ->
  D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\src\mongocxx\gridfs\downloader.cpp(80): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous [D:\mongo-inst\mongo-cxx-driver\build\src\mongocxx\mongocxx_mocked.vcxproj]
```

I've already tried installing different versions of c driver such as 1.13.0(which is the requirement for cxx-driver version 3.4.0), 1.15.0 and 1.14.1 but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't remember having that same problem but I had problems with the cmake and the boost versions suggested. Can you try with the cmake that you will find in your Microsoft VS, something like: "MicrosoftVisualStudio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
Also, I don't remember why but I ended up using boost_1.69.

If the above does not work, would you mind sharing your .vcxproj file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was not related to cmake version but boost version. Tutorial mentions boost 1.6 in the beginning but code snippets used 1.59 which caused confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue and it seems to stem from the boost version I used. Instead of 1.59, using 1.60 for boost version solved my issues.